# How can I setup android, ios and kotlin-frontend in the same kotlin-multiplatform project?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to set up a kotlin-multiplatform project with android, ios and web.
I'm using Android/iOS preset and then I'm trying to add js with kotlin-frontend-plugin. But unfortunately, as I already described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29453)it cause a conflict with an android plugin. Is it possible to set it up in a separate module to be able to use common code?